# Determining Savepoint Support in MySQLConnector with .NET Core

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

I am using .NET Core with MySQL and [MySQLConnector.net](https://mysqlconnector.net/) and encountered an issue regarding the behavior of the SupportsSavepoints method in MySqlTransaction. Despite the savepoints API being implemented, the method consistently returns false.

I am puzzled by this inconsistency and would like to understand the reasoning behind it. Is this behavior intentional or an oversight?

I create a connection to a MySql 8 database and check for the SupportSavepoints feature of the transaction:

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection("a ConnectionString");
var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
Console.WriteLine("Transaction.SupportsSavepoints: {0}", CurrentTransaction.SupportsSavepoints);
// writes: Transaction.SupportsSavepoints: false
```

Thank you in advance for the clarification!